# change the text of template when create

Tags: javascript, html, css

this code is working fine, but what I am trying to do not accomplished 100%...

problem: I have to use "10 times" custom checkbox in a form so I create a template containing my custom checkbox code.

need: Now what I want when new checkbox is created, div that contain text for checkbox is different what I want. like class ".checkbox_txt" in template contain computer science same checkbox but name is Algebra and so on
how can I do this without rewriting same code

```js
function myFunction() {
            const template = document.querySelector(".template");
            const contain = document.querySelector(".contain");

            let clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);

            contain.appendChild(clone);
        }
```

```css
* {padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
body {transform: translate(50%, 50%);}
.create {
    display: inline-flex; gap: 10px; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.create:hover .checkbox {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.checkbox {
    display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
    border: 2px solid gray; border-radius: 2px;
    width: 15px; height: 15px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.icon {
    /* display: none; */
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all 10s ease;
}

.create:hover .icon {
    display: block;
    transform: scale(1);
}
.checkbox_txt {
    font-weight: bold;
}

button {
    transform: translateX(-300%);
}
```

```html
<template class="template">
        <div class="create">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-check icon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox_txt">Computer Science</div>
        </div>
        <br>
</template>


<div class="contain">
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Create new box</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change the `textContent` of the clone.  Like so:

```js
function myFunction(textContent) {
  const template = document.querySelector(".template");
  const contain = document.querySelector(".contain");

  let clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
  if (textContent) {
    clone.querySelector('.checkbox_txt').textContent = textContent;
  }
  contain.appendChild(clone);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let content = [ "one", "two", "stuff" ]
  
  for (let elem of content) myFunction(elem)
})
```

```css
* {padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
body {transform: translate(50%, 50%);}
.create {
    display: inline-flex; gap: 10px; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.create:hover .checkbox {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.checkbox {
    display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
    border: 2px solid gray; border-radius: 2px;
    width: 15px; height: 15px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.icon {
    /* display: none; */
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all 10s ease;
}

.create:hover .icon {
    display: block;
    transform: scale(1);
}
.checkbox_txt {
    font-weight: bold;
}

button {
    transform: translateX(-300%);
}
```

```html
<template class="template">
  <div class="create">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-check icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox_txt">Computer Science</div>
  </div>
  <br>
</template>


<div class="contain">
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Create new box</button>
```

Comment: can we do this using just html like we do with rects js,

Comment: You don't do it with "just html" when using react.  You're using mechanisms that React provides that do a similar thing.